# Porting Language Invention Queries from Other Stacks

Tags: discussion

Simply put, and in light of a recent query about forum activity, what is the general thought of Constructed Languages SE regarding the importation of (perhaps somewhat older) language invention questions from other SE forums?  Particularly Worldbuilding, which was around rather before CL.SE and even now gets a number of language related queries (which are often referred here).

Main considerations: is this possible?; and if so, is this desirable?

Answer (score 3):

If you see interesting questions on other sites that would be on-topic here, and haven't already been asked here yet, go for it. Remember to properly reference the original if you use its content.

But only do that if you have a genuine interest in the question. Systematically transferring content will not help, nor will the Stack Exchange staff look favourably upon it if its purpose is to make this site look more active than it really is.

Comment: Of course, the point isn't to make this forum "look more active than it is" --- the point is to "make this forum more active"!  Also, invented language queries are increasingly frowned upon (in e.g., Worldbuilding) since we started up this forum.  It seems to make sense to bring over (or at least copy) older questions from there simply because we are language inventors and can give the old questions a new set of eyes and a more experienced perspective.